# Strange error about expecting a type

Tags: rust

I have this precise object and function definition:

```
pub struct Mep<Ins> {
    instructions: Vec<Ins>,
}
impl<Ins> Mep<Ins> {
    pub fn crossover<F>(parent0: &Mep<Ins>, parent1: &Mep<Ins>, mut random_point_generator: F) -> Mep<Ins>
        where F: FnMut(usize) -> usize, Ins: Clone {/*Body omitted*/}
}
```

The function compiles fine, but I receive the same error even for an empty function definition when calling it:

```
tests/mep.rs:14:33: 14:34 error: expected type, found `|`
tests/mep.rs:14     let c: Mep::crossover(a, b, |x| rng.next_u32() % x);
```

I also tried different parameters:

```
pub fn crossover<F>(parent0: &Mep<Ins>, parent1: &Mep<Ins>, points: usize, mut random_point_generator: F) -> Mep<Ins>
    where F: FnMut(usize) -> usize, Ins: Clone {}
```

It results in the same error:

```
tests/mep.rs:14:33: 14:34 error: expected type, found `3`
tests/mep.rs:14     let c: Mep::crossover(a, b, 3, |x| rng.next_u32() % x);
```

I am fairly new to rust and everywhere I look online discusses issues people have with obvious generics problems, but they aren't shared with my case as far as I can tell. What do I need to do to call this function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Variable assignment in rust is done with an equals sign, not a colon. So your statement should be

```
let c = Mep::crossover(a, b, 3, |x| rng.next_u32() % x);
```

If you want to also specify a type, you need both the colon with a following type AND an equals sign with the expression afterwards:

```
let c: Mep<Ins> = Mep::crossover(a, b, 3, |x| rng.next_u32() % x);
```